# Cannot run particular SPARQL query using Apache Jena

Tags: java, sparql, jena, apache-jena

I'm trying to run the following query using Apache Jena

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX vrank:<http://purl.org/voc/vrank#>
PREFIX dbp-ont:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp-prop:<http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT distinct (SAMPLE(?slabel) AS ?sublabel) (SAMPLE (?plabel) AS ?predlabel) (SAMPLE(?olabel) AS ?oblabel) ?v 
FROM <http://dbpedia.org/> 
FROM <http://people.aifb.kit.edu/ath/#DBpedia_PageRank> 
WHERE {
    {   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Yao_Ming> ?p ?o.
        FILTER regex(str(?o),"http://dbpedia.org/resource","i").
        FILTER (?p != dbp-ont:wikiPageWikiLink && ?p != <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> 
                && ?p != dbp-prop:wikiPageUsesTemplate && ?p != rdfs:seeAlso 
                && ?p != <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#differentFrom> 
                && ?p != <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageDisambiguates> && ?p != <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects> ).
        OPTIONAL {?o rdfs:label ?olabel. FILTER langmatches( lang(?olabel), "EN" ). }.
        OPTIONAL {?p rdfs:label ?plabel. FILTER langmatches( lang(?plabel), "EN" ).}.
        OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Yao_Ming> rdfs:label ?slabel. FILTER langmatches( lang(?slabel), "EN" ).}.
        OPTIONAL {?o vrank:hasRank ?r. ?r vrank:rankValue ?v}.
    } 
UNION
    {   ?s ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Yao_Ming>.
        FILTER regex(str(?s),"http://dbpedia.org/resource","i").
        FILTER (?p != dbp-ont:wikiPageWikiLink && ?p != <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> 
                && ?p != dbp-prop:wikiPageUsesTemplate && ?p != rdfs:seeAlso 
                && ?p != <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#differentFrom> 
                && ?p != <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageDisambiguates> && ?p != <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects> ).
        OPTIONAL {?s rdfs:label ?slabel.   FILTER langmatches( lang(?slabel), "EN" ). }.
        OPTIONAL {?p rdfs:label ?plabel.  FILTER langmatches( lang(?plabel), "EN" ).}.
        OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Yao_Ming> rdfs:label ?olabel. FILTER langmatches( lang(?olabel), "EN" ).}.
        OPTIONAL {?s vrank:hasRank ?r. ?r vrank:rankValue ?v}.
    }
} group by ?v order by desc (?v)
```

This query is taken from the [LinkSUM project](http://km.aifb.kit.edu/services/link/). It runs fine([results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20vrank%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fvoc%2Fvrank%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbp-ont%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbp-prop%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20distinct%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Fslabel%29%20AS%20%3Fsublabel%29%20%28SAMPLE%20%28%3Fplabel%29%20AS%20%3Fpredlabel%29%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Folabel%29%20AS%20%3Foblabel%29%20%3Fv%20%0D%0AFROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2F%3E%20%0D%0AFROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpeople.aifb.kit.edu%2Fath%2F%23DBpedia_PageRank%3E%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%09%7B%09%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FYao_Ming%3E%20%3Fp%20%3Fo.%0D%0A%09%09FILTER%20regex%28str%28%3Fo%29%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%22%2C%22i%22%29.%0D%0A%09%09FILTER%20%28%3Fp%20%21%3D%20dbp-ont%3AwikiPageWikiLink%20%26%26%20%3Fp%20%21%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fsubject%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%26%20%3Fp%20%21%3D%20dbp-prop%3AwikiPageUsesTemplate%20%26%26%20%3Fp%20%21%3D%20rdfs%3AseeAlso%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%26%20%3Fp%20%21%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23differentFrom%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%26%20%3Fp%20%21%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FwikiPageDisambiguates%3E%20%26%26%20%3Fp%20%21%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FwikiPageRedirects%3E%20%29.%0D%0A%09%09OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fo%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Folabel.%20FILTER%20langmatches%28%20lang%28%3Folabel%29%2C%20%22EN%22%20%29.%20%7D.%0D%0A%09%09OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fp%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fplabel.%20FILTER%20langmatches%28%20lang%28%3Fplabel%29%2C%20%22EN%22%20%29.%7D.%0D%0A%09%09OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FYao_Ming%3E%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fslabel.%20FILTER%20langmatches%28%20lang%28%3Fslabel%29%2C%20%22EN%22%20%29.%7D.%0D%0A%09%09OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fo%20vrank%3AhasRank%20%3Fr.%20%3Fr%20vrank%3ArankValue%20%3Fv%7D.%0D%0A%09%7D%20%0D%0AUNION%0D%0A%09%7B%09%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FYao_Ming%3E.%0D%0A%09%09FILTER%20regex%28str%28%3Fs%29%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%22%2C%22i%22%29.%0D%0A%09%09FILTER%20%28%3Fp%20%21%3D%20dbp-ont%3AwikiPageWikiLink%20%26%26%20%3Fp%20%21%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fsubject%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%26%20%3Fp%20%21%3D%20dbp-prop%3AwikiPageUsesTemplate%20%26%26%20%3Fp%20%21%3D%20rdfs%3AseeAlso%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%26%20%3Fp%20%21%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23differentFrom%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%26%20%3Fp%20%21%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FwikiPageDisambiguates%3E%20%26%26%20%3Fp%20%21%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FwikiPageRedirects%3E%20%29.%0D%0A%09%09OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fs%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fslabel.%20%20%20FILTER%20langmatches%28%20lang%28%3Fslabel%29%2C%20%22EN%22%20%29.%20%7D.%0D%0A%09%09OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fp%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fplabel.%20%20FILTER%20langmatches%28%20lang%28%3Fplabel%29%2C%20%22EN%22%20%29.%7D.%0D%0A%09%09OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FYao_Ming%3E%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Folabel.%20FILTER%20langmatches%28%20lang%28%3Folabel%29%2C%20%22EN%22%20%29.%7D.%0D%0A%09%09OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fs%20vrank%3AhasRank%20%3Fr.%20%3Fr%20vrank%3ArankValue%20%3Fv%7D.%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%20group%20by%20%3Fv%20order%20by%20desc%20%28%3Fv%29%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)) on the dbpedia sparql endpoint but no rows are returned by Jena.

This is the code

```
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSetFactory;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP;

        String query = "..."; // The previously mentioned query
        String DBPEDIA_SPARQL_SERVICE = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql/";
        QueryEngineHTTP qExec = (QueryEngineHTTP) QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(DBPEDIA_SPARQL_SERVICE , query);
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            resultSet = qExec.execSelect();
            resultSet = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(resultSet);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Report exception
        } finally {
            qExec.close();
        }

        String subLabel = "sublabel";
        String predLabel = "predlabel";
        String obLabel = "oblabel";
        String vRank = "v";

        if (resultSet != null) {
            while (resultSet.hasNext()) {
                QuerySolution result = resultSet.next();
                if (result != null) {
                    System.out.println(subLabel);
                    System.out.println(predLabel);
                    System.out.println(obLabel);
                    System.out.println(vRank);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have run several queries using the same code but this one fails to return any results.

Comment: Print out somethign on all code paths. May be tesultSet is null because "// Report exception". Also you do not have "?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org".

Comment: As @AndyS said, it's bad practice to do nothing for the exception case. And write `qExec.addDefaultGraph("http://dbpedia.org");`

Comment: I'm actually logging the exception. I just excluded that code here. Also, I'll try adding the default graph

Comment: The default graph did the trick! @AndyS you should make your comment the answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBpedia requires `?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org` in the servce URL or alternatively `qExec.addDefaultGraph("http://dbpedia.org");` sometimes.  This seems to be the case here when using `FROM` in the query.